# Remove session from ci_sessions table on logout

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I have implemented Codeigniters cart class which automatically enables sessions (what I gather from documentation) and stores the session data into my ci_sessions table in the db.

However, when I logout as a user, the session remains in the db. If log back in, the old session remains and new one is created. Is this correct? On login, I'm never really checking the ci_sessions table for an existing session, is this something I need to implement or is it something codeigniter handles automatically?

Here is my function for logging in and logging out, I unset the session variables but this in itself doesn't remove the session from the db.

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); // Don't forget to call the parent constructor in this method

  }

  public function dashboard() {
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('user/dashboard');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
  }

  public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('landing_page');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

    public function register() {
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('user/register');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

    public function login() {
        $this->load->view('template/header');
        $this->load->view('user/login');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

  public function registerUser() {
    //form validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error" style="color: red;">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('dob', 'Date of Birth ', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_1', 'Address One', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_2', 'Address Two', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('postcode', 'Postcode', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('county', 'County', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password One', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('passwordagain', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password1]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      //if form validation fails, send user back and display errors
      $this->register();
    } else {
      //prepare data for insert to db
      $data = array(
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'date_of_birth' => $this->input->post('dob'),
        'address_1' => $this->input->post('address_1'),
        'address_2' => $this->input->post('address_2'),
        'postcode' => $this->input->post('postcode'),
        'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
        'county' => $this->input->post('county'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $this->hashPassword($this->input->post('password1'))
      );

      $this->User_model->insertUser($data);
      redirect('user/index');
    }
  }

  public function loginUser() {
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error" style="color: red;">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      $this->login();
    } else {
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->hashPassword($this->input->post('password'));

      $user_id = $this->User_model->login($email, $password);

      if($user_id) {
        $user_data = array(
          'user_id' => $user_id,
          'email' => $email,
          'logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);

        redirect('user/dashboard');
      } else {
        redirect('user/login');
      }
    }
  }

  // Log user out
  public function logout(){
    // Unset user data
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('email');

    // Set message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedout', 'You are now logged out');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();

    redirect('user/login');

  }

  function hashPassword($password) {
       return md5($password);
   }
}
```

Config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'applicationcookie';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Added my config.php above. I'm using the database as the session driver.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly set the `session` in your `login controller`. That's why the `session` is remaining.

I assume you have autoloaded the session under the `application/config/autoload.php`.

The array what you have created is correct.

```
$user_data = array(
          'user_id' => $user_id,
          'email' => $email,
          'logged_in' => true
       );
```

Next set it to the session as follows.

`$this->session->set_userdata('login_session',$user_data);`  //Here you made mistake.

Once the session is set, redirect the user to dashboard or homepage.

To `log out` the user, use below code

```
if($this->session->userdata('login_session'){
    $this->session->unset_userdata('login_session');

    // Set message
    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_loggedout', 'You are now logged out');
    redirect('user/login');
}else{
    redirect('user/login');
}
```

Now every time when the user opens your website, check if the user's login session is active.

Under constructor add this code.

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{

   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      if(!($this->session->userdata('login_session'))){
         redirect('user/login','refresh');
      }
 }
```

Similarly, in your login controller, check if the login session is active.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata('login_session')){
            redirect('user/dashboard','refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit - If you have both the methods in a single controller then use this code**

```
class User extends CI_Controller{
     public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          if(!$this->session->userdata('login_session')){
              redirect('login','refresh');
          }
      }

      public function login(){
          $this->load->view('login_view');
      }

      public function dashboard(){
          //since in controller I'm checking the session, you need not have to check it in the dashboard.
          $this->load->view('dashboard_view');
      }
 }
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would I not set the session when the user has been verified to login?

Also, I don't have separate controller for login, dashboard etc. They are just methods in my User controller, how would I check for the session everytime in relation to my code?

Comment: You were setting the session but not unsetting it when you logged out the user. So you had that issue. If you don't have a separate controller, then use the condition at the function level.

Comment: What you have suggest above still doesn't work. The session in the database persists, even after clicking logout with your code. Could this be due to the fact my User controller is the main controller?

Comment: Why you want to store the session in the database. Any particular reason. Codeigniter by default wisely handles the session.

Comment: Sorry, bro. I made a mistake. I've modified my answer again.

Comment: I have added my config.php to show that I'm using the database as the session driver. Would I need to compare the session ID's and the remove accordingly?

Comment: I generally use and recommend default session configurations. Because the database can be hacked very easily. I use `$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL`. This configuration has never created me issues.

Comment: When there are thousands of users using the website especially login/logout operation, you are increasing the SQL traffic for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

When they click logout, send them to a controller/method that [destroys the session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session).

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

This should invalidate the session and prevent you from accessing it further. CodeIgniter will clean up expired sessions in the db on it's own, you do not need to do garbage collection.

Comment: Destroying the session will lead to destroying of all users sessions. I think you shouldn't suggest this to anyone.

Comment: You are mistaken. Session destroy only destroys the current session when it is called. This is clearly explained in the documentation I have linked to.